# Barcode scanning with .net maui

Tags: .net, xamarin.android, camera, maui, xamarin-studio

I am working to read barcode using .Net Maui and I found something which uses the device's default camera. However the app that I am working needs to use device's integrated barcode reader instead of camera. How this can be achieved either with .Net MAUI or XAMARIN.

Comment: Most of barcode readers works as a keyboard, in my actuall application, i have a hidden entry focused which reads the barcode but since i'm working with a low android api, i can't hide the keyboard, it works with new api versions, if you want i can share you an approach of code

Comment: Since you haven't told us anything about the device you are using it's difficult to say.  I suggest you start by reading the manual.  It may have an API to control the scanner, or it may rely on the "wedge" method mentioned by @LeandroToloza

Comment: Thanks Jason. I am using a Zebra ZT720 device and I don't wish to use the keyboard wedge method as in my app there are some pages where they don't have any input fields and user should be able to scan the barcode directly and read the data from image. Existing application was written in UWP and the approach followed was using a "Windows.Devices.PointOfService". Is there something similar in MAUI

Comment: You will likely need to use a generic class in the main MAUI code and then inject a platform specific barcode class within the Windows section of the solution. Although MAUI doesn't support UWP there may be something similar in the Windows App SDK.

Answer (score 0):

For Zebra devices, it is recommended to use Zebra DataWedge.

See https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/latest/guide/api/softscantrigger/  here for example.

(manual is written for Xamarin, but usage in Maui is pretty much the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [xzing barcodescanner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/net-maui-zxing-barcode-scanner/)

From their website:
The successor to ZXing.Net.Mobile: barcode scanning and generation for .NET MAUI applications. First, we need to add the ZXing.Net.MAUI library to our project as a dependency. To do this, open the NuGet Package Manager and search for "ZXing.Net.MAUI". Install the package in your .NET MAUI project.

```
// Add the using to the top
using ZXing.Net.Maui;
// ... other code
public static MauiApp Create() {
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder.UseMauiApp & lt;
    App & gt;
    ().UseBarcodeReader(); // Make sure to add this line
    return builder.Build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides keyboard mode, most Android devices with built-in barcode scanners support Broadcast mode. When the barcode scanner picks up a barcode, it sends a broadcast message, and your app registers to listen to these broadcast messages. Make sure to change scanner barcode output to Broadcast mode in the phone's settings. Here is a code snippet

```
// MainActivity.cs in Platforms/Android folder
// BroadcastName and KeyValueName are device model specific. Replace them with yours
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    private readonly BroadcastReceiver barcodeReceiver = new BarcodeBroadcastReceiver();

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        RegisterReceiver(barcodeReceiver, new IntentFilter("BroadcastName"));
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        UnregisterReceiver(barcodeReceiver);
        base.OnPause();
    }
}

public class BarcodeBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override async void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Get the received message from the Intent
        var barcode = intent.GetStringExtra("KeyValueName");

        // call your method of .Net MAUI
    }
}
```