# How can I scan barcodes on sheets and retrieve the reference in .NET Maui C# using Zebra?

Tags: android, .net, maui, zebra-scanners

I am developing an application in .NET Maui and C#, and on a certain page, I want to scan the barcode on a sheet without using a button and retrieve the reference. I have searched everywhere on the internet, but I have not found a suitable solution. If possible, I would like to use DataWedge.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ZoneEnCours.Models"
             x:Class="ZoneEnCours.Views.FenZEScanfs"
             x:DataType="model:ModelFenZEScanfs"
             Title="{Binding Titre}">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1.8*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label x:Name="Atelier"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Text="{Binding Soustitre}"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="25"
               FontSize="30"
               FontAttributes="Bold" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Text="{Binding Texte}"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="25"
               FontSize="20"
               FontAttributes="Bold" />

        <Image Grid.Row="2"
                Source="barcode.png" />

        <Label Grid.Row="3"
               x:Name="Reference" 
               Text="Reference"/>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

I tried to use datawedge, ZXing...

Comment: when you say "DataWedge" do you mean a hardware scanner device?

Comment: DataWedge is a software using by a Zebra Device to scan barcode. But is you bring me a solution without DataWedge I take

Answer (score 0):

As I answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74180548/barcode-scanning-with-net-maui/74656349#74656349), it should be pretty straightforward following the official Zebra DataWedge manual and its code example.

I will try to give you the main bulletpoints here.
First you need a class inheriting the BroadcastReceiver class, something like this:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;

[BroadcastReceiver]
  public class DataWedgeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
private Context _context = null;

// This intent string contains the source of the data as a string
private static readonly string SOURCE_TAG = "com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.source";

// This intent string contains the barcode symbology as a string
private static readonly string LABEL_TYPE_TAG = "com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.label_type";

// This intent string contains the captured data as a string
// (in the case of MSR this data string contains a concatenation of the track data)
private static readonly string DATA_STRING_TAG = "com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.data_string";

// Intent Action for our operation
public static string IntentAction = "barcodescanner.RECVR";

public static string IntentCategory = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT";

private static readonly string ACTION_DATAWEDGE_FROM_6_2 = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION";
private static readonly string EXTRA_CREATE_PROFILE = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.CREATE_PROFILE";
private static readonly string EXTRA_SET_CONFIG = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG";
private static readonly string EXTRA_PROFILE_NAME = "PROFILE_NAME";

public DataWedgeReceiver()
{
  _context = Android.App.Application.Context;

  CreateProfile();
}

public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent i)
{
  // check the intent action is for us
  if (i.Action.Equals(IntentAction))
  {
    // define a string that will hold our output
    string scannedData = "";
    // get the source of the data
    string source = i.GetStringExtra(SOURCE_TAG);
    // save it to use later
    if (source == null)
      source = "scanner";
    // get the data from the intent
    string data = i.GetStringExtra(DATA_STRING_TAG);
    // let's define a variable for the data length
    int data_len = 0;
    // and set it to the length of the data
    if (data != null)
      data_len = data.Length;

    // check if the data has come from the barcode scanner
    if (source.Equals("scanner"))
    {
      // check if there is anything in the data
      if (data != null && data.Length > 0)
      {
        // we have some data, so let's get it's symbology
        string sLabelType = i.GetStringExtra(LABEL_TYPE_TAG);
        // check if the string is empty
        if (sLabelType != null && sLabelType.Length > 0)
        {
          // format of the label type string is LABEL-TYPE-SYMBOLOGY
          // so let's skip the LABEL-TYPE- portion to get just the symbology
          sLabelType = sLabelType.Substring(11);
        }
        else
        {
          // the string was empty so let's set it to "Unknown"
          sLabelType = "Unknown";
        }

        // let's construct the beginning of our output string
        scannedData = data.ToString();
        MessagingCenter.Send("Datawedge", "BarcodeScanned", scannedData);
      }
    }        
  }
}

private void CreateProfile()
{
  string profileName = EXTRA_PROFILE_NAME;
  SendDataWedgeIntentWithExtra(ACTION_DATAWEDGE_FROM_6_2, EXTRA_CREATE_PROFILE, profileName);

  //PROFILE
  //  Now configure that created profile to apply to our application
  Bundle profileConfig = new Bundle();
  profileConfig.PutString("PROFILE_NAME", profileName);
  profileConfig.PutString("PROFILE_ENABLED", "true"); //  Seems these are all strings
  profileConfig.PutString("CONFIG_MODE", "UPDATE");
  Bundle appConfig = new Bundle();
  appConfig.PutString("PACKAGE_NAME", _context.PackageName);      //  Associate the profile with this app
  appConfig.PutStringArray("ACTIVITY_LIST", new string[] { "*" });
  profileConfig.PutParcelableArray("APP_LIST", new Bundle[] { appConfig });

  //BARCODE READER
  Bundle barcodeProps = new Bundle();
  barcodeProps.PutString("barcode_trigger_mode", "1");
  Bundle barcodeConfig = new Bundle();
  barcodeConfig.PutString("PLUGIN_NAME", "BARCODE");
  barcodeConfig.PutString("RESET_CONFIG", "true"); //  This is the default but never hurts to specify
  barcodeConfig.PutBundle("PARAM_LIST", barcodeProps);      

  //INTENT
  Bundle intentProps = new Bundle();
  intentProps.PutString("intent_output_enabled", "true");
  intentProps.PutString("intent_action", IntentAction);
  intentProps.PutString("intent_delivery", "2");
  Bundle intentConfig = new Bundle();
  intentConfig.PutString("PLUGIN_NAME", "INTENT");
  intentConfig.PutString("RESET_CONFIG", "true");
  intentConfig.PutBundle("PARAM_LIST", intentProps);

  // Add configurations into a collection
  profileConfig.PutParcelableArray("PLUGIN_CONFIG", new Bundle[] { barcodeConfig, intentConfig });
  SendDataWedgeIntentWithExtra(ACTION_DATAWEDGE_FROM_6_2, EXTRA_SET_CONFIG, profileConfig);

private void SendDataWedgeIntentWithExtra(string action, string extraKey, Bundle extras)
{
  Intent dwIntent = new Intent();
  dwIntent.SetAction(action);
  dwIntent.PutExtra(extraKey, extras);
  _context.SendBroadcast(dwIntent);
}

private void SendDataWedgeIntentWithExtra(string action, string extraKey, string extraValue)
{
  Intent dwIntent = new Intent();
  dwIntent.SetAction(action);
  dwIntent.PutExtra(extraKey, extraValue);
  _context.SendBroadcast(dwIntent);
}
}
```

Most of this code is quite messy and only intended to setup a proper DataWedge profile in your device, which you can also do manually. Notice that when a barcode is received, it is then sent via MessagingCenter. You need to hook on this message elsewhere in the app to use the barcode however you like.

To use this DataWedgeReceiver class, set it up in your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
private DataWedgeReceiver _broadcastReceiver = null;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    _broadcastReceiver = new DataWedgeReceiver();
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    if (null != _broadcastReceiver)
        {
          // Register the broadcast receiver
          IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DataWedgeReceiver.IntentAction);
          filter.AddCategory(DataWedgeReceiver.IntentCategory);
          Android.App.Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver, filter);
    }    
}

protected override void OnPause()
{
    if (null != _broadcastReceiver)
    {
    // Unregister the broadcast receiver
    Android.App.Application.Context.UnregisterReceiver(_broadcastReceiver);
    }
    base.OnStop();
}
```

Comment: La classe MainActivity je dois la créer où et comme je l'utilise ensuite dans ma fenêtre ?

Comment: Quels sont les différents packages à installer, car j'ai déjà vue cette solution mais j'ai des erreurs sur `BroadcastReceiver`, `Context`, `Intent`, `Android.App`, `Bundle`, et sur la fonction `SendDataWedgeIntentWithExtra`

Comment: @SarahAllaire Hi, sorry, I don't speak french...

Comment: @SarahAllaire The MainActivity is the main class of every Android project. In .NET MAUI you can find it in Platforms>Android folder in your project
I also edited my answer to show necessary using statements

Comment: Okay thanks, and which packages i have to download, because I've created the class DataWedgeReceiver but i have many errors.

Comment: @SarahAllaire No packages are needed for this class. Do you have your MAUI project set up in a way, that it builds for Android devices?

Comment: I think I didn't specify that it is built for Android because we can develop cross-platform applications with .Net MAUI

Comment: @SarahAllaire It is true, MAUI is meant for cross-platform development. However, Zebra devices are Android only, as far as I know, and the code I posted as answer is meant for Android, because it is for Zebra DataWedge. Simply put, code that is meant for Android, should be in the Android part of your project and it won't be built for other platforms.

Comment: Ok I moved the class and I included to my file these elements : ```using Android.Content;
using Android.OS; ```

Comment: But I still have mistakes. For the function ```SendDataWedgeIntentWithExtra``` I get the error ```The modifier 'private' is not valid for this element```. Do I have to put it in public?  In addition, two functions have the same name and I had problems with conversion, so I gave two different names.

Comment: Okay I just erased the ```private``` and I modified the MainActivity, now how can I use it in my Window ?

Comment: @SarahAllaire I dont want to sound condescending, but it sounds like you're developing something entirely different than I adviced you for. Could you share more of your project code perhaps? Ideally a git repo with your whole solution?

Comment: Okay no problem I organize it.

Comment: https://github.com/sarahallaire/ZoneEnCours2