# How do I receive the scanned bar code from Zebra MC3300x to my .net Maui program?

Tags: maui, barcode, barcode-scanner, zebra-scanners

I am trying to build a .net Maui app for a Zebra MC3300x (it has a built in scanner). However, I'm having a hard time finding out how to get the result from the barcode scan. For ease of visiblity I had even set it so that the scan result should be shown in a label.Text of mine.

I have tried following the advice from this link exactly like how it's posted but it still doesn't work. - [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155324/how-can-i-scan-barcodes-on-sheets-and-retrieve-the-reference-in-net-maui-c-shar)

I have tried putting a breakpoint on the start of the OnReceive but no matter how many times I scan a bar code, the OnReceive method never stops on my breakpoint which leads me to believe that the OnReceive isn't triggering when a scan is made.

I have also tried changing the "MessagingCenter.Send("Datawedge", "BarcodeScanned", scannedData);" to a WeakReferenceMessenger and had also put a breakpoint but again, it still didn't work.

Please advise on what needs to be done so that the program would recognize when a scan is made. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I was able to resolve this by simply turning on the Keystroke option(profile settings from Data Wedge) and associating the profile with the .net maui program. Instead of sending intent, I instead put focus on an Entry so that whenever a bar code is scanned, the results would be written on the entry that is being focused on.

This not only worked, it also doesn't require any coding on my program since the bar code scan results simply gets written on the entry.

Comment: How about to use an Entry in your page to scan the barcode there? It is not an acceptable solution for you? This way you do not need to do something special, except that you must configure Zebra to send Enter after barcode and define a Complete event handler for the Entry.

Comment: I'd love to do that. However I'm unable find a way to make the scan results even show up. How would I make the scan result appear?

Comment: You have to do nothing special, but the "BarcodeEntry" must have focus when barcode is scanned.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean exactly. The OnReceive doesn't seem to trigger when I scan a barcode. What do I have to change so that the OnReceive triggers when i scan a barcode?

Comment: Most hardware scanners are configured to act as input devices.  The scan results will appear as keyboard input in your app, so the should automatically appear if an Entry control has focus when you scan.  You can test this by scanning with any text editor app open.  Fot more information you need to read the device manual